# How do i make use if?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to programming and I've been working on a game of rock, paper, scissors. It all works except for the last part (the `if` part).

```
x = ("rock")
y = ("paper")
z = ("scissors")
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
choices1 = (x, y, z)
choices2 = (x, y, z)
import random
print("player 1 chose...")
print(random.choice(choices1))
print("player 2 chose...")
print(random.choice(choices2))
if random.choice(choices1) = rock and         random.choice(choices2) = scissors:
 print("player 1 wins")
```

Whenever i try executing the script, it says this:

```
File "<string>", line 14
 if random.choice(choices1) = rock and random.choice(choices2) = scissors:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Unless you are using Python `0.9` you should be using `==` ;)

Comment: @jamylak Docs or you are joking.

Comment: @Haidro It doesn't have docs but see for yourself http://www.python.org/download/releases/early/

Answer (score 4):

You need `==` not `=`:

```
if random.choice(choices1) == "rock" and random.choice(choices2) == "scissors":
    print("player 1 wins")
```

Secondly as you've not declared any variables named `rock` and `scissors`, then you must use quotes around them to make them strings otherwise you'll get `NameError`.

or use the variables `x`,`z` that point to the strings "rock" and "scissors":

```
if random.choice(choices1) == x and random.choice(choices2) == z:
    print("player 1 wins")
```

`==` is used for checking equality and `=` is for assignments.

```
>>> "foo" == "bar"
False
>>> "foo" == "foo"
True
```

As assignment is not allowed in python's `if` statement you're getting `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Worked so i've finished the rest of it now

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator for equality is `==` not `=`.

`=` is used to assign items to an object, eg `var = 5`. Hence the `SyntaxError`.

### From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming):

The standard comparison operators are written the same as in C: `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `==` (equal to), `<=` (less than or equal to), `>=` (greater than or equal to) and `!=` (not equal to).

---

Also, `rock` is not defined, so you will also obtain a `NameError`. I'm presuming it should be a string, so make it `"rock"`.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator must be == not =. Look at following details:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm